# Issues Sending MIDI information on iOS Applications

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, midi, coremidi

So I've been stuck trying to get MIDI information to send to my computer from the iOS application I am building for my iPad.  I setup the client, and output port, and obtain the end reference point as well.  MIDI Monitor on my Mac reads the MIDI System Execution Message when I start up my iPad but nothing else happens.  I have a very general MIDISend message trying to send a note on message but that isn't very successful.  I have my iPad connected via IDAM MIDI Host through Audio MIDI Setup but can't get anything to transfer.

I have already tried using Core MIDI's various options such as get Source, get entity Source, get destination, nearly all return the same type of property of IDAM MIDI Host.  I have print statements everywhere in my code trying to figure out where my issue is but I am stuck now since I cannot figure out what is wrong.

Here are some functions I have made within a class, to create a client, create an output port, and send the MIDI information:

Some variable declarations outside these functions:

```
func openClient(){
   MIDIClientCreate("Gregs iPad" as CFString, nil, nil, &midiClient)  
}



func createPort(){
      MIDIOutputPortCreate(midiClient, "Output" as CFString, &outputPort)

}
```

func obtainSource(){

```
    // determine how many devices are connected
    midiDevice = MIDIGetDevice(2) // this is IDAM MIDI Host
    let entcount = MIDIDeviceGetNumberOfEntities(midiDevice)  // number of entities
    ent = MIDIDeviceGetEntity(midiDevice, 0) // obtain the entity reference

    // obtain the end point ref from this entity
    midiSource = MIDIEntityGetDestination(ent, 0)
    midiSource2 = MIDIEntityGetSource(ent, 0)



// Trying to send some MIDI within this function
    let pack = UnsafeMutablePointer<MIDIPacket>.allocate(capacity: 1)
    let packLst = UnsafeMutablePointer<MIDIPacketList>.allocate(capacity: 1)
    //let midiDataToSend:[UInt8] = [UInt8(0xB0), UInt8(0x0A), UInt8(20)];
    let midiDataToSend:[UInt8] = [UInt8(0x90), UInt8(60), UInt8(100)];
    MIDIPacketListInit(packLst);
    MIDIPacketListAdd(packLst, 1024, pack, 0, 3, midiDataToSend);

    MIDISend(outputPort, midiSource, packLst)
    MIDIReceived(midiSource, packLst)
    print(packLst)

}
```

I also tried using MIDIReceived to see if anything would send as well, but no success. I would expect to see some information sent to my DAW on that specific status and data bytes declaration but nothing seems to work successfully.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else viewing this, I figured it out.  The packet variable needs to be assigned to the packetlist initialization to be passed through as a pointer for the packet list add function. In the last section of my code you need to change: var pack = UnsafeMutablePointer.allocate(capacity: 1), and then set that equal to the initialization (pack = MIDIPacketListInit(packLst);). I noticed this after I read the MIDIPacketListAdd Function and realized that the currentpacket argument input HAD to be a pointer. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: What does that mean? Can you show some corrected code?

Comment: In the last section of my code you need to change:  var pack = UnsafeMutablePointer<MIDIPacket>.allocate(capacity: 1), and then set that equal to the initialization (pack = MIDIPacketListInit(packLst);).  I noticed this after I read the MIDIPacketListAdd Function and realized that the currentpacket argument input HAD to be a pointer.  Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: I’m suggesting you might put that in the answer, to help future users.